# Работа с sed. Копирование из одного файла в другой

Tags: windows, sed

Пытался скопировать с 3697 по 3967 строку файла `my.html` в файл `mynew.html` и получил следующую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как добиться результата копирования.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса // текст, кстати, помог бы идентифицировать, что за символ вы использовали вместо обычной одинарной кавычки `'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Раз не понимаешь, как пользоваться консолью, используй полные пути ко всему.
2. Windows понимает только нормальные кавычки (`"`) для группировки аргумета.